# css positioning relatively to parent element and page/viewport

Tags: css

I have a custom tooltip implemented in CSS

```
<td class="has_tooltip">
    some text
    <div class="tooltip">hello I am a tooltip</div>
</td>
```

`tooltip` has `position:absolute`. I can set the `position` of `has_tooltip` to `relative` and position the tooltip relatively to the parent element, but I want to also position it relatively to the right edge of the page, so it would be something like this:

```
.tooltip{
    bottom: calc(100% + 30px) relative to parent element
    right: 10px relative to page
}
```

Is that possible with pure CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you know, with reasonable degree of precision, where the right edge of each element with the "has_tooltip" class is in relation to the right edge of the viewport. Setting the "right" property to a negative value, possibly in conjunction with calc() or a right margin, can do that with the said limitation. Otherwise, you would need to set a reasonable default in your stylesheet and override it for each tooltip with JS.

Comment: Thanks, using my knowledge of how far each element is from the right solved my problem. (although an ugly code repeating lots of `:nth-child` selectors, but all that matters is that it works :P)